# How to access newly created files on a repo via the Github API?

Tags: github, github-api

I can access existing files just fine. For example, this works perfectly to retrieve the contents of README.md at the root of the repo:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents/README.md
```

However, if I create a new file at the root of the repo called 'test.txt', I get a 'Not Found' error when I try to retrieve it like so:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/kevindecent/decent-salesforce/contents/test.txt
```

Why can't I access newly created files at the root of the repo, using the Github API? Is my access token corrupt or something?

Comment: If you created the file locally, did you push it to the remote first?

Comment: @tomerpacific yeah the new file is sitting on the remote on the master branch. It's like the Github API is looking at some older cached version of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I was making a simple mistake. I was returning the contents of a forked version of the repo using this URL:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<Github User Name>/decent-salesforce/contents
```

When I should've returned the contents at the **organization** level using this URL:

```
https://api.github.com/repos/<Github Organization Name>/decent-salesforce/contents
```

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), and its [associated scope](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps#available-scopes) (at least `repo`), as well as its possible expiration date.

Use said token directly in command-line to see what is going on:

```
curl -v -i -u your_username:$token https://api.github.com/...
```

Comment: Checked my PAT, it has full permissions.

Comment: @kevdecent OK. What does the curl command show?

Comment: I think I figured out what's happening. I ran the curl command, and got a the contents of a fork of the repo at my user level. I'm trying to access the repo at my organization's level, not at my personal account level. I'll see if I can play around with it a bit to get it to work.